# Result is being rounded up [C]

Tags: c, floating-point

I've been writing this program in C, and I've noticed that the division result, captured in the `fee` variable, has always fixed value, and that is **5.00**, but the result should be **5.78**.
Can you explain why it has this behaviour and what should I do to fix it
?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

    printf("Input package dimensions: width, heigth, length \n");
    int width, height, length;
    scanf("%d", &width ); 
    scanf("%d", &height ); 
    scanf("%d", &length );

    int weight = width*height*length;
    printf("%d\n", weight);
    float fee = weight/166;

    printf("%.2f\n", fee);
    printf("The fee is : $%.2f\n and", fee); 

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even though `fee` is a `float`, `weight` is an `int` -- this means that the result of `weight/166` will be an `int`, and rounded.

Comment: Integer division discards the remainder.

Comment: That should be 'rounded down'.

Comment: This is known as implicit conversion... Know more about it here:,http://clanguagebasics.com/c-language-tutorial/c-type-conversion-implicit-explicit-type-conversion-in-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line `weight` and `166` will be divided as integers and then cast to `float`.

```
float fee = weight/166;  // integer division
```

You need to cast or define one of them as float for a more accurate division.E.g.

```
float fee = weight/166.0; // double precision division
```

Or

```
float fee = (float) weight/166; // single precision division (float)
```

Or if you want to surprise your colleagues :

```
float fee = weight/166.0f; // single precision division (float)
```

Comment: Found `float fee = weight/166.0;` is not the same as `float fee = (float) weight/166;`.  The first does the division using `double` math.  The 2nd may only use `float` math.  Try `weight == 16777217`.  (Just trying to  surprise my colleagues. :-))

Comment: @chux that is correct. And because you made me actually compile and test my examples, I found that my last recommendation doesn't compile (`error: invalid suffix "f" on integer constant`)

Answer (score 4):

Thats because you are dividing int by int. To get a floating point number at least one of them should be a floating number.

```
float fee = weight/166.0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Both `weight` and `166` have type `int`, therefore `weight/166` is an integer division, which truncates any fractional part.  The fact that you assign the result to a variable of type float is irrelevant.

You want to instead perform floating-point division, which you can accomplish by ensuring that at least one of the operands has a floating-point type.  One of the simplest ways to do that would be

```
float fee = weight / 166.0;
```

Comment: Won't that do `int` -> `double` -> (division) -> `float` conversion?

Comment: @Amit, yes it will.  Division of `double`s is floating-point division, just as division of `float`s is (and in practice, division of `float`s is often performed as division of `double`s anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
float fee = (float)weight/166.0;
```

Otherwise an integer-division is performed and *then* casted to float.

Answer (score 3):

```
float fee = weight/166;
```

`166` is `int` and `wight` is `int`. `int` divided by another `int` will always result in `int` and only when the result is stored in `fee`, it is casted to `float`.

You can fix it by

```
float fee = (float)weight/166;
```

or by

```
float fee = weight/166.0;
```

Comment: [Difference in the 2 methods.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34095209/result-is-being-rounded-up-c#comment55944327_34095255).

Answer (score 2):

That's because dividing an integer by an integer results in an integer, And that's what `weight/166` does. It is later covered to a floating point, but that's "too late".

The most explicit way to have a floating point division in your case is:

```
(float)weight / 166.0f
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it.

```
float fee = weight/166.0;
```